# How to make a shortcut to do batch processing in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I want to

1. publish my Asp.Net MVC project to my local IIS and
2. launch my default browser pointing to the site/application.

I know Visual Studio can do the same thing but using a different scenario, i.e.,

1. launching built-in web server and web browser, or
2. launching web browser pointing to the project associated with local iis virtual directory.

How can I create a shortcut to do batch processing as mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

To script publishing the site you'll need to call MSbuild and ask that to publish the site. See http://codingcockerel.co.uk/2008/05/18/how-to-publish-a-web-site-with-msbuild/ for details on this.

You can lauch the site from a script with a line like:

```
start iexplore "http://localhost:12345/"
```